# how to pass string params in Get call of API using axios in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios, query-string

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    posts: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?id=2&id=3')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ posts: response.data })
        
      })
  }

  render() {
    return( 
    <div>
         {
          this.state.posts.map ( (el,k) => <li> {el.title} </li> )
         } 
          </div>
  )}
}

export default App;
```

I am learning how to pass query params while calling APIs. The above code is working fine for me. Here i have passed id=2&id=3 as query params. I am using the following URL

> https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

Now, I am failing  to pass *title* in the URL as params also. For e.g. the key-value pair of id=5 is "title": "nesciunt quas odio". So what is the proper way to pass it? Since the *title* has string value with the spaces in between.

My code should print the titles of id=2, id=3 and id=4; but for id=4 i shall pass the title itself in the params instead of id.

So, following command is rendering nothing on DOM

```
Axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?id=2&id=3&title=eum et est occaecati')
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to syntax this is to split it with `&`.

Example:

```js
Axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?id=3&title=ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut')
```

Once you input this you'll see that the browser replaces the spaces with `%20`,
but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: this command only printing the title of 2nd id

Comment: Yes, apologies, my mistake. Fixed it.
Notice the `&` instead of a comma, and the lack of `"` between the title.

Comment: still not working

Comment: That's strange, you can literally paste this link `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?id=3&title=ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut` and see the JSON within your browser.

Comment: here you have misinterpret the question. Suppose i want to print the title of id=2, id=3, and id =4 ( but not by passing the id for the fourth instead by passing title in the params).

Answer (score 0):

trying to use this way

```
    axios({
        method: 'get',
        params: {
            "id" : 1,
            "id" : 2,
            "title" : "test"
        },
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
        responseType: 'json',
    }).then((response) => {})
```

the axios handle the rest

Comment: not working, facing other issues

Answer (score 0):

you can use the params option for axios

```
Axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
     params : {
          id : 1,
         title : "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut"
        }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use 'encodeURIComponent' to encode strings containing special characters like space in the url

```
'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?title=' +
        encodeURIComponent('eum et est occaecati')
```